# Link won't work within grid of clickable boxes in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an interactive Jeopardy board where the user can click on any number value and go to the relevant question page (the back end for this will be done later).

The problem is that the first two columns can't be clicked on (the link doesn't work) as well as half of the third column as indicated in the picture below:

[image]

The gray circles indicate the parts that can't be clicked. The red boxes are the bounds of the boxes I'd like to be clickable.

I realize that this is connected to the **width: 17%;** property in my CSS Style page, however making this higher makes it impossible for me to place the clickboxes where I'd like to place them. I've tried multiple other approaches as well to no avail.

If there's a more efficient way to do this, I'm all ears.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.board{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 1250px;
 height: 680px;
 background-image: url("../rsc/board.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.column{
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.board::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

body {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    background-image: url("../rsc/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
}


a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Jeopardy!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
    </head>
    <body> 
 <?php
        //Get POST data
  $username = $_POST['username'];
 ?>
 <h1 style="color: white;">Welcome, <?php echo $username ?>! This is Jeopardy!</h1>
 
 <div class="board">
  <div class="column">
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 160px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 25px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 22px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 270px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 160px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 25px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 22px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 220px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 160px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 25px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 22px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 95px; margin-top: 160px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 95px; margin-top: 25px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 95px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 95px; margin-top: 22px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-left: 95px; margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-top: 160px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-top: 25px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-top: 22px;"></a>
  <a href="questions.html" style="margin-top: 23px;"></a>
  </div>
 

 </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest just making buttons and using JS to link them to the site, plus you could also get form data to let the user no which one has been clicked/used already and deny them from clicking on it again.

Comment: It worked! Switched to a grid of invisible buttons and didn't have to sacrifice anything.